# angular - how to use setcustomvalidity function

Tags: angular, html

I try to used the html setcustomvalidity method to set my biz validation, but the form cannot block the custom validity. How to use this function at angular?

form:

```js
export class AutoComponent {
  autoFiled: any;
  
  @ViewChild('autoForm') autoForm;
  @ViewChild('autoInput', { read: ElementRef}) autoInput: ElementRef;
  
  check() {
    if (autoField != '123') {
      this.autoInput.nativeElement.setCustomValidity('Not Equals 123');
      this.autoForm.submitted = true;
      return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form novalidate #autoForm="ngForm"
  [class.invalid]="!autoForm.submitted">
  <input #autoInput type="text" name="auto" [(ngModel)]="autoField"/>
</form>
```

Comment: for the setCustomValidity(), sounds like need to use reportValidity() funciton. Reference: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#dom-cva-reportvalidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Validation in template driven form you need to create custom directive

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomVaidator]',
  providers:[{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useValue: equalCheck,
    multi: true
  }],
  exportAs:'appCustomVaidator'
})
export class CustomVaidatorDirective {
  constructor() { }
}
function equalCheck(c:AbstractControl){
  if(!c.value) return null;
  return  c.value != 123 ? { notEqual: true} : null;   
}
```

Ref::https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-drive-form-customvalidator

Comment: the useValue looks like be used at function, I modified to useExisting it can be used to export class, and than it only be fired when value changed, did there has any tags to be fired when form submit.thanks

Comment: You want to get form submitted status?